# Add period to entire PPT besides Titles using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to add periods to the whole PowerPoint presentation excluding the titles of each slide?

I currently am using the below code which puts a period after everything:

```
Sub AddPeriod()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods
    Next shp
Next sld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is:

```
Sub AddPeriod()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim strTitle As String

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If sld.Shapes.HasTitle = True Then 'check if there is a title
            strTitle = sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Else
            strTitle = ""
        End If
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            'add periods only if text of shape is not equal to title text.
            If strTitle <> shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Then
                 shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub
```

This will check the text of the title vs. the text of your shape.  If they are the same, it will not add the periods.  Perhaps there is some sort of indicator on the shape that states whether the shape is the title, but I couldn't find it.  You need to check to make sure the slide has a title, otherwise getting the string from the text of the title shape will cause an error.

Comment: When I ran this code, it gave me run time error: "specified value is out of range" and highlighted the `If strTitle <> shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Then` line. Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: Perhaps shp.TextFrame.TextRange is empty?

Comment: Or the TextFrame itself is empty?  I'd try examining the Shape to see where the problem is.